# PySpark: How to create a struct column containing the same value?

Tags: pyspark

Normally, you can create a column with a singular value like so

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("single_value", F.lit(1))
```

but I can't seem to find the equivalent for struct columns.

This works but I think there should be something better.

```
df.withColumn("dummy", F.lit(1)).withColumn("dummy2",
  F.struct(
    F.col("dummy")
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

```
spark_df.withColumn("dummy2",
                F.struct(
                    F.lit(1).alias("col1")
                )
            )
```